# Portion of iPad simulator screen responsive to swipes, but not button clicks

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7, ios-simulator, xcode5

I have a UICollectionViewController in a container.  On a specific portion of the screen (bottom right area in Landscape), it will register swipes, but the sections of buttons in that area are non-responsive.

The buttons are the top items in the view, so nothing overlays them.  Only a portion of the button is non-responsive, and only when it is in that area of the screen.  It is consistently the same area in every collectionView that is in a container.

Has anybody encountered this issue?  Any potential causes or fixes?

Comment: This type of problem is usually due to a UI element being outside the bounds of its superview. If you can give the superview a background color it will make it obvious whether this is the cause or not.

Comment: fwiw, I've seen something similar with modal view controllers with a translucent background - the problem I saw was toward the top of the screen tho. If I made the background a solid color it was fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  I was using "freeform" viewControllers, and they were messing with my superview size.  So, as rdelmar pointed out, my problem was that the buttons were outside the superview.

I solved the problem by deselecting "Resizes View From NIB" in my freeform viewControllers.